# CSS and setting "display" with media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

So suppose I have the following code:

```
td.topnav_link {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: #5babd7;
  border: 1px solid #578baf;
  cursor: default;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #id_topnav_link_menu.topnav_link {
    display: block;
  }
  #id_topnav_link_about.topnav_link {
    display: hidden;
  }
  #id_topnav_link_contact.topnav_link {
    display: hidden;
  }
}
```

and

```
<td class="topnav_link" id="id_topnav_link_contact">
<a href="/contact/">contact</a>
</td>
```

should the "about" and "contact" not become hidden when I resize the browser down? (It does not for me when testing in a variety of browsers)

(Note: Yes, I realize I am using a **td** where I should not, but I am slowly converting an old layout of mine to be more CSS and more mobile)

Comment: You can't use display: none/block on table cells.

Comment: @Itay Itai: Well you *can* use `display: none` on table cells, but instead of `block` it should be `table-cell`.

Comment: @BoltClock♦: You are right. I was mistaken.

Comment: You should definitely avoid tables for layout on mobile sites. Mobile browsers have drastically different rules for handling tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `hidden` value for `display`. It should be `none`. But as it is a cell, you should use `visibility`, which will hide the cell, but the space will still remain there:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #id_topnav_link_menu.topnav_link {
    display: block;
  }
  #id_topnav_link_about.topnav_link {
    visbility: hidden
  }
  #id_topnav_link_contact.topnav_link {
    visbility: hidden
  }
}
```

Here's a list of possible values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: Sorry for mistaking you, as BoltClock♦ has told me, you can give it display: none but display: block should be replaced with display: table-cell.

Comment: I think if you set `display: block` on a cell it will be computed as `table-cell`, like `inline` on float is computed as `block` anyway.

Comment: My problem has been solved. Can't believe I made that error :(